# puTTY and remote desktop work with Raspberry Pi when it is not plugged in, why?

Tags: remote-desktop, putty, connection, raspberry-pi

I have recently been able to figure out how to launch the remote desktop using the IP address in wlan0 for my raspberry pi zero W. For some reason, PuTTY and remote desktop can access the pi when it is not plugged into the computer or a power source. I only know some stuff about how servers work when using the internet, but as a general question, shouldn't PuTTY and remote desktop not be able to access the pi if it is not plugged into any power source/computer? Or my computer can access the server for the pi and then when I plug it in or give it a power source, anything I have done updates to the pi?

Comment: Wait... you have a pi zero and have no cables attached whatsoever and can still access it... I want one :) Kidding aside... your pi zero will only work if it has power. So no power, no access. If you do have access, maybe you're accessing another pi zero on your network (which you forgot about) :)

Comment: Rik is right: you can't possibly be connecting to a computer that has no power since, well, it has no power. :)

Answer (score 2):

If your RasPi is not connected to power (USB or pin header) it can't run and therefore can't be accessed.
Make sure you are not accidentally accessing a different host to the one you thought you where accessing.